# What is correct Linq syntax to get multiple aggregate results from a list of integers in single iteration

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of integers and I want to calculate: Count, Max, Min, Average using Linq syntax.  I know that the following all work fine:

```
var avg = list.Average();
var max = list.Max();
```

and so on.  But I can't figure out the correct Linq syntax to do this in a single iteration, i.e. the equivalent of SQL:

```
select Min(value), Max(value), Avg(value) from list
```

Comment: What's wrong with doing them the way you've shown?

Comment: @TJWolschon OP has to iterate on the same list multiple times

Comment: There is a trick with group by constant, but it usually it's used in LINQ to some database query translators. In LINQ to Objects it makes sense only if you want to iterate the *source* sequence once.

Comment: If you want truly one iteration over the source collection, it appears you'll have to implement the aggregates yourself.

Comment: @glenebob: I did see some examples which implemented the aggregates, but it seems more code clutter than what it would be just to do it in a loop.

Comment: @Eser If it's actually a list, then *iterating over it multiple times isn't a problem at all*.  Since it doesn't represent a sequence that causes side effects, always yields the same values, and isn't expensive to compute, iterating over it multiple times is perfectly fine.

Comment: @servy Since benchmarking is the mantra, for 10 million random `Int32`s, I get `foreach` at 1, `Aggregate` at 1.17 and multiple LINQ functions (`Count`,`Min`,`Max`,`Average`) at 2.80, so multiple times can be considerably slower. With `double` sums, it is 2x and 2.9x.

Comment: @Servy :) You do that way.

Comment: @NetMage And is the actual data set being used 10 million items?  And relative times aren't what's important, it's absolute times that are important.  Is the extra few milliseconds actually going to be a user-impacting performance issue or not?  Maybe it is for that context, if so, then by all means optimize it out, but iterating over a materialized sequence to do nothing tends to go *very* fast in most contexts.

Answer (score 2):

If your list is `src`, you can use a `ValueTuple` and `Aggregate` to make a hard to read loop:

```
var ans = src.Aggregate((Count: 0, Min: Int32.MaxValue, Max: Int32.MinValue, Sum: 0),
                        (g, v) => (g.Count+1, v < g.Min ? v : g.Min, v > g.Max ? v : g.Max, g.Sum+v));
var count = ans.Count;
var min = ans.Min;
var max = ans.Max;
var avg = ans.Sum / (double)(ans.Count == 0 ? 1 : ans.Count);
```

Of course, if it is something you might want to do often, you can create an extension method for it:

```
public static class IEnumerableExt {
    public static (int Count, int Min, int Max, double Average) Stats(this IEnumerable<int> src) {
        var a = src.Aggregate((Count: 0, Min: Int32.MaxValue, Max: Int32.MinValue, Sum: 0),
                              (g, v) => (g.Count + 1, v < g.Min ? v : g.Min, v > g.Max ? v : g.Max, g.Sum + v));
        return (a.Count, a.Min, a.Max, a.Sum / (double)(a.Count == 0 ? 1 : a.Count));
    }
}
```

The loop version is more verbose but arguably easier to understand:

```
public static (int Count, int Min, int Max, double Average) Stats2(this IEnumerable<int> src) {
    var count = 0;
    var min = Int32.MaxValue;
    var max = Int32.MinValue;
    var sum = 0;

    foreach (var i in src) {
        ++count;
        if (i < min)
            min = i;
        if (i > max)
            max = i;
        sum += i;
    }

    return (count, min, max, sum / (double)(count == 0 ? 1 : count));
}
```

Comment: *sum* should be *float/double*, not *int* AND what what if *src* is empty?

Comment: @L.B Then you will get a divide by zero error :) - I added code to handle. Not sure about `sum`, that depends on OP needs, but perhaps average should be double.

Comment: I don't think OP would want a *avg=0* for a list *[1,1,0]*.

Comment: @L.B Again, depends on purpose. If you are doing pixel graphics, 0.667 pixels isn't possible. But I already changed average to be double. `Sum` should be double if it might exceed `Int32.MaxValue`, but that also depends on source and I wouldn't trade int addition for double addition unless I knew it was needed.

Comment: I would prefer to use *Math.Round* or *Math.Floor* or *Math.Ceiling* instead of a code returning wrong results...

Comment: Returning an `int` result for average gives an implicit `Math.Floor`.

Comment: But let me to decide how I use the avg.

Answer (score 1):

What about this? Before select, order list ASC will be useful

```
List<double> list = new List<double>() { 15,116,17,21,333,44,55,11};

double max = 0;
double min = 0;
double avg = list.OrderBy(x => x).Select((x, index) => index == 0 ? min = x : max = x).Average();
```

Hope helps,